# Argument of type '{ toString: () => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | WordArray'

Tags: angular, typescript, string

```
hash: function hash(key: { toString: () => any; }): any {
      key = CryptoJS.SHA256(key, SECRET_KEY);
      return key.toString();
    }

**(parameter) key: {
    toString: () => any;
}
Argument of type '{ toString: () => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | WordArray'.
  Type '{ toString: () => any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'WordArray': words, sigBytes, concat, clamp, clonets(2345)**
```

It was working fine until I have updated the angular version and now I am getting this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try doing it like this. I Dont know exactly how you are implementing it but this works for me

```
 public yourVariable = {
    hash: (key: { toString: () => any }) => {
      key = CryptoJS.SHA256(key, SECRET_KEY);
      return key.toString();
    }
  }
```

and then you call it like this

```
console.log(this.yourVariable.hash(YouStringorHasg));
```